# How to set different c++ compiler for different targets for a same project in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a c++ project, it has 2 modules, each as a target. target A need compile with g++4.8, target B need compile with g++7, how should i compose the CMakeLists.txt for this purpose? i tried many effects but still cannot succeed, thanks in advance!

Thanks & Regards,
Martin.

Comment: "target A need compile with g++4.8, target B need compile with g++7" - This cannot be done in a single CMake project. See duplicate questions and their answers for more details.

Comment: Thanks Tsyvarev! seems i worked it around by using create a few subfolders and use add_subdirectory(...), then i can use diff compiler for each subfolder modules.